# Send mail through bash script

Tags: bash, email

Hey I was just wondering when I trying to create a bash script which can send mail. To start off I was testing mail out using the command line but when I run the command nothing happens. I suppose the command tries to send it but it never goes through and it just hangs and I have to send the kill letter.

These are the commands i have tried:

```
mail -s "Subject" email@.com
mailx -s "Subject" email@.com
```

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for you to enter the message body on standard input?

Comment: it doesnt prompt me for any additional information. i even tried sendmail command but after the subject it hung again

Comment: Those commands don't prompt for input, they assume it will be provided on the standard input.  Try entering a message body and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to send a *message* with your mail. We can also try *verbose* mode:

```
$ mailx -v -s "Test Message" foo@bar.com <<EOM
> This is my message I want to send.
> I can keep typing it and the last line ends with just "EOM"like this:
> EOM
Mail Delivery Status Report will be mailed to <foo>.
$
```

The `<<EOM` is called a [Here Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). It tells your computer to expect input to direct to the command from STDIN (the keyboard), and that the input will end with the string that followed the `<<` characters (here `EOM`).

You'll get a *mail report* emailed to you. You can use `mailx` to read it, or one of those fancy new email programs like [`elm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elm_(email_client)) or [`pine`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pine_(email_client)), or just read your mail from the command line via `mailx`:

```
$ mailx
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/foo": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 MAILER-DAEMON@davebo  Mon Nov 24 14:04  67/2465  "Mail Delivery Status Report"
? s
No file specified: using MBOX.
"/home/users/foo/mbox" [New file]
? q
$
```

Now, you should have a file called `mbox` in your `$HOME` directory. Take a look at this file, and see what it says. I got this:

```
$ vi $HOME/mbox

Enclosed is the mail delivery report that you requested.

                   The mail system

<foo@bar.com>: delivery via
    mail.foo.com[XX.XX.XX.XX]:25: host
    mail.foo.com[XX.XX.XX.XX] refused to talk to me: 554
     -Please submit an unblock request 
    <http://x.co/rblbounce>
```

Looks like I'm blocked.

Answer (score 0):

With the syntax you use, mail is certainly waiting for you to type a message on standard input, as suggested in the comments. You could:

--type a message yourself after the command, terminating with a C-d

--Use syntax like this to write a string to the body:

```
mail -s "Subject" foo@bar.com <<< "Hello"
```

--Different syntax

```
echo "Hello" | mail -s "Subject" foo@bar.com
```

Especially if you are going to be sending mail in a script, you would want to consider either of the last two approaches.

Comment: hey alright this actually i believe submits it but i get no message to the email i am testing to. It is possible to send to a live.ca domain right?

Comment: There should be no problem sending to specific domains. You could also try adding the `-v` flag to the mail command and then view the generated mail delivery report.

Comment: oh ok thanks. i suppose it just takes time to send the mail. and how would i know which email it would be sent from? the machine will use its own email right? sorry if stupid question

Comment: and how do i check the mail delivery reports? i tried looking around cant seem to find it

Comment: hey i typed in mail in the command line and just noticed this:

<aimsupp@domain>: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for
    name=domain type=MX: Host not found, try again